# Why do UpLaTex display Chinese text with Japanese punctations instead of Chinese punctations

Tags: cjk

When I tried to compile my file containing Chinese text vertical style using dvipdfmx, it ended up compiling the text which was written with Chinese punctuation where the period, 。 and 、 are supposed to be in the middle like most of the Taiwanese novels I have seen to punctuation more like Japanese style which is on the top right of the last character.

I looked on the website for UpTex itself and the example pdf for vertical Chinese looked appropriate when I downloaded it. Yet after using dvipdfmx on it it goes back to Japanese style punctuations.

Is there a package I can use to fix the punctuation so it will look appropriate?

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{utarticle} % dvipdfmx driver option (for color) required, for post-processing of dvipdfmx
\usepackage{color} % not required for this example...
\begin{document}
\section{不動 明王}
足球部隊長。位置MF，背號10。留著龐克頭且頭上塗有紅色的油彩。3期中，頭髪有一部分染白，而將油彩塗掉，背號變為8號。說話都使人討厭而很看扁別人、雖然會為了勝利不擇手段、但實力強到足以和鬼道相比。
被影山利用成為真・帝國學園的一員要來打倒雷門、似乎被吉良所認同（因此在遊戲版第二代中對古蘭燃起了對抗的心），但和外星學園的關係不明。把影山當作拿來討好吉良用的道具而已、而他的真意也被影山所看透、使他說出其募集能力和足球實力可說是「二流的」。過去因為父親被公司不當解僱而背負大筆債務、而否定父親的母親向他說出「成為偉大的人來讓大家好好見識一下」，造成他的人格有巨大的影響。
必殺技為「球場殺戮者」（鬼道）、「皇帝企鵝3號G3」（佐久間＆鬼道）。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Post a MWE; an minimal working example .tex file which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Could this be a simplified vs traditional problem? I think in mainland usage the punctuation marks would be more like the ones you got a actually.

Comment: @Rethliopuks I was using traditional Chinese in my text.

Comment: By "post a MWE", I meant that you have to copy and paste the **content** of jpn.tex; otherwise nobody can answer your question.

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA Should I upload a pdf file to show where the offending punctuation error are?

Comment: Real reason: upLaTeX is developed by Japanese; so probably *everything* will follow Japanese style. Using a Traditional Chinese font will *slightly* resolve this problem.

Comment: @Symbol1 How do I set up the Traditional Chinese font?

Comment: @RowanDao Fonts sold by Taiwanese seller will follow TC style. Multilingual fonts such as **Source Han Sans** and **Source Han Serif** will tell you how to choose TC style properly in their manual. The idea is that you should either use a TC font, e.g. `\fontspec{華康少女體}`, or use a multilingual font with proper options. In any case, reading xeCJK's manual might help. Reading fontspec's manual migh help as well.

Comment: upLaTeX can be used to generate Chinese documents, and the easiest way is to call pxbabel package; I will post an answer

Answer (score 2):

By default, upLaTeX is optimized for Japanese texts. If you like to use traditional Chinese, you can write for example:

```
\documentclass{utarticle}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}% unnecessary after updating to 2017/05/29 v1.1
\usepackage[main=tchinese]{pxbabel}
% change the behavior of \normalfont for \section etc.
% here we use tchinese = J23, defined in pxbabel
%\def\kanjiencodingdefault{J23}% unnecessary after updating to 2017/06/19 v1.1a
\begin{document}
\section{不動 明王}
足球部隊長。位置MF，背號10。留著?克頭且頭上塗有紅色的油彩。3期中，頭髪有一部分染白，而將油彩塗掉，背號變為8號。?話都使人討厭而很看扁別人、雖然會為了勝利不擇手段、但實力強到足以和鬼道相比。
被影山利用成為真・帝國學園的一員要來打倒雷門、似乎被吉良所認同（因此在遊戲版第二代中對古蘭燃起了對抗的心），但和外星學園的關係不明。把影山當作拿來討好吉良用的道具而已、而他的真意也被影山所看透、使他?出其募集能力和足球實力可?是「二流的」。過去因為父親被公司不當解?而背負大筆債務、而否定父親的母親向他?出「成為偉大的人來讓大家好好見識一下」，造成他的人格有巨大的影響。
必殺技為「球場殺戮者」（鬼道）、「皇帝企鵝3號G3」（佐久間＆鬼道）。
\end{document}
```

Save the above code as "tchinese-vert.tex" and execute

```
$ uplatex tchinese-vert
$ dvipdfmx tchinese-vert
```

then you will get

[image: Example of traditional Chinese vertical writing on upLaTeX]

[Note] When the result is still wrong (= roman letters are messed up with kanji characters), there is something wrong in the embedded fonts themselves. For example, I know that [arphic-ttf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arphic-ttf) fonts (bsmi00lp.ttf = ShanHeiSun-Light, bkai00mp.ttf = ZenKai-Medium; these are freely available and set as default embedding fonts by TeX Live) do not work as expected in vertical writing.

In such case, you should choose other fonts by executing

```
$ kanji-config-updmap-sys --tc adobe % when you choose Adobe fonts
$ kanji-config-updmap-sys --tc ms    % when you choose Microsoft fonts
```

etc., and re-run dvipdfmx. The above choice is supported by "[ptex-fontmaps](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ptex-fontmaps)"; if you want to know what embedding fonts can be used, see the result of the following:

```
$ kanji-config-updmap-sys --tc status
```

If you don't have any fonts with vertical support, then you may choose

```
$ kanji-config-updmap-sys --tc noEmbed
```

By executing this, dvipdfmx does not embed any traditional Chinese fonts; as a result, the actual fonts are determined by PDF viewers -- then, whether the result is correct depends on PDF viewer.

Comment: The punctuation looks correct when I compile your example tex into pdf but I think the roman letters look off like this:
![Messed up roman letters](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1zqDNcVO6Y4WGZhV29jaGE4bE0).

Comment: As I already wrote in the answer, when arphic-ttf fonts are used, the result is wrong as you pointed (I experienced the same result as your "Messed up roman letters"). However, when you choose other fonts (adobe, ms, etc -- all these are not included in TeX Live due to non-free), the result will be ok.

Comment: Added a little more comments about kanji-config-updmap-sys spec to answer